# How to change a php read file using jscript and php. New Q how to stop it effecting the header

Tags: php, html, mysql, redirect, readfile

**Note this still does not work as intended it does not put the information into the page instead it just redirects to a new page**

**Update**
New problem is that I dont want the user seeing a massive header that is my reason for using this readfile system is there any way i can avoid massive headers when i change the contentFile ? thanks in advance
is this doable from the .htaccess file or will this not be an option

thanks in advance

My question is, is it possible to change a readfile using ajax, jscript or html. So if a user click a button in the php it changes the read file

Example

```
//display content    
<?php
    $contentFile = "content.php";
    readfile( $contentFile );
?>
```

Redirect

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   document.getElementById("myButton").onclick = function () 
{
                       location.href = "./content2.php";
};
</script>

    <p>TO POPULATE THE TABLES CLICK THE BUTTON: 
           <button id="myButton2" class="float-left submit-button" >changecontent</button></p>
                        </br>
   //
```

Any help would be amazing

**UPDATE** 
working code below

```
  <section id="content" class="content">
    <button id="newButton" class="float-left submit-button" >changecontent</button></p>
        </br>
    <?php
    if(isset($_GET['filename'])){
        $contentFile = $_GET['filename'];
    }else{
        $contentFile = 'content.';
    }
    readfile( $contentFile.'php' );
    ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById("newButton").onclick = function()
    {
        location.href= "test.php?filename=content2.";
    };  
    </script>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Try this logic
 PHP code...
 if(isset($_GET['filename'])){
     $contentFile = $_GET['filename'];
 }else{
     $contentFile = 'content1';
 }
 readfile( $contentFile.'.php' );

<script type="text/javascript">
   document.getElementById("myButton").onclick = function () 
{
      location.href = "change_file.php?filename=content2";
};
</script>
```

Comment: I recieve 2 errors. ( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: filename in C:\wamp\www\phpAdminSite\test.php on line 172
Call Stack
# Time Memory Function Location
1 0.0281 255288 {main}( ) ..\test.php:0

( ! ) Warning: readfile(): Filename cannot be empty in C:\wamp\www\phpAdminSite\test.php on line 173
Call Stack
# Time Memory Function Location
1 0.0281 255288 {main}( ) ..\test.php:0
2 0.0726 257144 readfile ( ) ..\test.php:173

Comment: Above mentioned issue will get resolved with my updated answer..Please have a look

Comment: The code works it displays the first readfile which i could do anyway but when i start to try and change the $contentFile it still shows me the default one any help ?

Comment: It means your location.href is not getting call...have you click on your "myButton" button..if click on that it should redirect user to change_file.php?filename=content2...and should take content2.php file...are you getting any error when click on button?

Comment: Okay ive got it semi working now. I have one problem though my whole reason of using this readme system is that the users will not see in the header where they are going. Is there anyway to resolve this issue ill update my problem now

Comment: Please post your next problem..will try to resolve it.

Comment: Hi there i have updated it did you manage to find a fix ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning wrong id, use the below javascript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   document.getElementById("myButton2").onclick = function () 
{
                       location.href = "./content2.php";
};
</script>
```

Hope this helps you